# Firebase database equal query with array of string

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to download only nodes where name is "String1" or "String2" or "Str.. .How can I do this. Do I need to pass array of string in equalTo method of firebase.

Comment: Try `orderByChild(childKey).startAt("string1").endAt("string10")`. I think it will give you values like `string1`, `string2`, `string3`, .. `string10`

Comment: @koceeng it will return the consective records but we don't want this.